# Proxy. Thinking process. How can i kill them?

Tags: java, exception, proxy, bufferedreader

Some times work throuw the proxy server and reading prom buffer content my program to think so more time... until i close them. How set program code that from some seconds if do not have any answer from server to take another server?

```
URL url = new URL(linkCar);
String your_proxy_host = new String(proxys.getValueAt(xProxy, 1).toString());
int your_proxy_port = Integer.parseInt(proxys.getValueAt(xProxy, 2).toString());
Proxy proxy = null;
//  System.out.println(proxys.getValueAt(xProxy, 3).toString());
//  if (proxys.getValueAt(xProxy, 3).toString().indexOf("HTTP") > 0)
//  {
proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(your_proxy_host, your_proxy_port));
//  } else {
//  proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress(your_proxy_host, your_proxy_port));
//  }

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
connection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
connection.connect();

String line = null;
StringBuffer buffer_page = new StringBuffer();
BufferedReader buffer_input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(),"cp1251")); 
int cc = 0;

//this is thinking place!!!
while ((line = buffer_input.readLine()) != null && cc < 7000) {
   buffer_page.append(line);
   cc++;
}

doc = Jsoup.parse(String.valueOf(buffer_page));
connection.disconnect();
```

i tried to use counter but it not work... What exception i can use to catch this situation by my control?

Comment: [`URLConnection.setReadTimeout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout(int)); reads that time-out will throw [`SocketTimeoutException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html).

Comment: Would you like me to post it as an answer for you to accept it properly?

Comment: some exception else? This get thinking process prom some proxies

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer if you can use StringBuilder. There is almost never a good reason to use StringBuffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`URLConnection.setReadTimeout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29). From the specification,

> Sets the read timeout to a specified timeout, in milliseconds. A non-zero value specifies the timeout when reading from Input stream when a connection is established to a resource. If the timeout expires before there is data available for read, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

As you can see, reads that time-out will throw [`SocketTimeoutException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html), which you can catch appropriately, e.g.

```
try (BufferedReader buffer_input = new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "cp1251"))) {
  String line;
  while ((line = buffer_input.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer_page.append(line);
  }
} catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
  /* handle time-out */
}
```

Note that you need to be careful when using `readLine` as above -- this will strip all `\r` and `\n` from the input.